# refreshing certain data after action

Tags: javascript, php

This is my code:

```
<input type="tekst" id="<?php echo $item->getId();?>">
<script>
    document.getElementById("<?php echo $item->getId();?>").value =<?php echo getVotesValue($item->getId());?>
</script>
```

I would like to have my actual like amount displayed, right after user clicks like button, now to see the new likes amount I have to refresh the page, likes are held on server.

this is my code responsible for adding like:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('a.like').on('click', function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.post(url, {}, function () {
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

so once again my goal is to have new value of likes displayed in `<input>` tag after clicking I tried to do :

```
$(function () {
    $('a.like').on('click', function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.post(url, {}, function () {
            document.getElementById("<?php echo $item->getId();?>").value =<?php echo getVotesValue($item->getId());?>
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

but it is not working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shoud use `data-...`

```
<a href="#" class="vote-up" data-id="<?php echo $item->getId(); ?>">Vote Up</a>
```

and click function

```
$('a.vote-up').click(function(e){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var url = 'likes.php?do=vote_up&id=' + id; // change to your PHP file
    $.post(url, {}, function(result){
        // you should return the total of likes in result
        $('#'+ id).val(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanksfor answer, Your script is working but not exactly what I meant. After klicking on the anchor I'm going all the way up, the like is added, BUT to see the likes amount counter increased (on page) I have to reload the page. And my goal is to musnnt need to reload

Comment: you sould return new count of likes after add the new like

Comment: this line do that `$('#'+ id).val(result);`  the result should return the new count and it will appear in the div#${id}

Comment: if you want to add +1 to the count only you can do that with `$('#'+ id).val(Number($('#'+ id)) + 1)` and it will work but from server side it will be better (y)